# Adding Google Sheets to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, dynamic, operations-dashboard, google-sheets, dashboard

I am building a Dashboard that relies on tabular data and that is located in a Google spreadsheet. Since the spreadsheet is dynamic and gets updated constantly, I would like those changes to be reflected in the Dashboard automatically and as soon as they occur. Thus, I am trying to add a Google Sheet to my ArcGIS Online content rather than a CSV file, but when I select the spreadsheet I always receive the following error message:

> *Cloud Drive file is invalid or not found*

These are the steps I take when I try to add the Google Sheet:

1. In the AGOL Content menu, I click on *Add Item* and choose *From a Cloud Drive*
2. I select *Google Drive* as my source.
3. I change the File Type to *Google Sheets* and select the spreadsheet from my drive. This is when the error message pops up.

I have tried a similar process in the Map Viewer but I still receive the same message that the file could not be found. I also published the Google Sheet to the web first but I still cannot load it into AGOL.

I would like to mention that other Google Sheets in my Drive can be added but this one is giving me trouble. The Google Sheet in question includes several formulas (IMPORTRANGE, ARRAYFORMULA, etc) and a large number of records (over 8,000). Could this be the problem? Is there a limit on the number of records that can be added via Google Sheets? Are the formulas causing these issues for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

among these listed could be a possible source of the error

1. Make sure there are no duplicate columns with the same name in your google sheets file
2. Make sure there are no records with missing coordinates in your google sheets file

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with importing Google Sheet Data into ArcGIS Online, it could be an issue with too many records. So you might want to download your Google Sheet data and convert to a .csv file, then upload into your ArcGIS Online Content.